# Unable to get Policies working in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization, policy

I've been following the Laravel Authorization docs trying to build "is the user allowed to do this" functionality by using Policies, but I can't get it to work. I keep getting `This action is unauthorized` and I've tried with route middleware too.

`PagePolicy.php`:

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Page;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PagePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the page.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Page $page)
    {
        return $user->id === $page->user_id;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create pages.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the page.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Page $page)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the page.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  App\Models\Page  $page
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Page $page)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

`PageController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use App\Models\Page;

use App\Http\Requests\PageRequest;

class PageController extends ApiController
{
    public function createNewPage(PageRequest $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('create', Page::class);

        $request->merge([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'published_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]);

        if (Page::create($request->all())) {
            return response()->json('success', 201);
        }

        return response()->json('error', 500);
    }

}
```

`AuthServiceProvidor.php`:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Page;
use App\Policies\PagePolicy;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Page::class => PagePolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that those ID's match?

Comment: Yes. I'm logged in as auth->id = 1 and page->user_id = 1

Comment: What about a dd() in the Policy Method? So you can see if it's actually called (and the objects are the ones you expect them to be)

Comment: @alvaric s answer should be correct. You need to put the Code of your "view" method in the policy to your "create" method that you're actually calling in your Controller

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I added the code view() to see if I could get it working, which is doesn't (not authorized) and, to me, it doesn't make sense to add the same code in the create as there is no user_id until the Page has been created. The docs show the create() method empty https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#writing-policies so I did the same. This is where I am getting confused. Also, where is the best place to add the dd() as I tried in the controller and Policy and get the unauthorized error before it's being triggered.

Comment: In your Controller you Trigger a policy check for the "create" privilege. So you should either replace the 'create' check to 'view' (makes more sense in that context anyways) or put some logic into your create method.

Comment: Cool, thanks again. I'll work on that now.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure it out. I wasn't using Route Model Binding. So I added `authorize()` after the page call and used the `$page` variable instead of `Page::class`.

```
public function update(PageUpdateRequest $request, $pageSlug)
{
    $page = Page::where(['user_id' => Auth::id(), 'slug' => $pageSlug])->first();
    $this->authorize('update', $page);
    $page->update($request->all());
    return fractal()->item($page, new PageTransformer())->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm not sure what you've done.

Comment: @Dubby did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear to me which action you're attempting to authorize since you've provided the call to create in the controller but only provided a policy check in place for viewing a page.  Having said that, I would be sure to var_dump/dd the values you're attempting to do a type comparison of to verify they're of the same type.  If anything's been explicitly cast, it may cause issues with certain database drivers that return integers as strings.

Comment: Hi. I've added a comment under Fabian's responses above. Not sure if that clears things up slightly.

Comment: Just to add to Fabian's comments and perhaps clarify the situation, Laravel will be looking for a function with the same name as the first argument passed to "$this->authorize".  If making this change doesn't fix things feel free to update your originally posted code to show the latest/greatest version in order to help further diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in your policies, rather in your `PageRequest` class. Make sure the `authorize()` method in your `App\Http\Requests\PageRequest` class returns `true` .

```
class PageRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
    * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true; // you can also check the authorization using PagePolicy here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Current code:

```
protected $policies = [
    Task::class => TaskPolicy::class,
];
```

Solution code:

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Task' => 'App\Policies\TaskPolicy',
];
```

---

I experienced the same problem, while following the [Intermediate Task List Tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart-intermediate#deleting-tasks) on the Laravel website.

The solution is actually present in the [Github code for this tutorial](https://github.com/laravel/quickstart-intermediate/blob/master/app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php).

Comment: This is basically the same thing, you must have messed up imports if this didn't work.

Comment: Laravel is converting Task::class to 'App\Task' in the background, so its the same thing!